# SQLitedatabase not inserting id for lollipop

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have the following code to insert contentValues in Database. I use the SQLitedatabase method insert() to insert values in database as follows:

```
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public boolean replaceOrUpdate(DBListener dbListener,final String sTable, ContentValues[] contentValues,String tag) {
    this.mDbListener=dbListener;

    if(mDatabase == null) {
        openDB();
    }
    mDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        int count = contentValues.length;
        for (int i=0; i<count;i++) {
            ContentValues value = contentValues[i];
            long id = mDatabase.replaceOrThrow(sTable,null,value);
        }
        mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDbListener.onCompleteInsertion(tag);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception = " , " " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        mDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
    return true;
}


public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesIDs()
{
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        if(mDatabase==null || !mDatabase.isOpen())
        {
            openDB();
        }
        String query="SELECT "+DBUtil.ID+" FROM "+TABLE_MERCHANT_STORES;
        Cursor  cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            ids.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBUtil.ID)));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }catch(SQLException sqx)
    {
        sqx.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return ids;

}
```

The table is created as follows:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+
            TABLE_MERCHANT_STORES +" ("+
            AUTO_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            DBUtil.ID       +" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, "+...)
```

This code works fine on pre-lollipop devices, but the insertion does not work as expected on lollipop. It seems to get stuck at certain values and continues inserting the missing values in the table. After insertion when I print all the values they appear in ascending order with a few intermediate values missing. The id values stored in the table are

1
2
3
4
5
7
11
13
14
15
16
17
19

whereas the values that gets inserted (expected) on pre-lollipop are:

514
533
531
312
434
162
253
252 
151
344
153
160
658

The error pattern seen on lollipop devices is that when an id is inserted in  the table, it seems that the query continues inserting in the gaps between last greatest ID and current greatest id as long as the next id it receives is not greater than the current id inserted. Is this a bug in lollipop sqlite? Or is it something specific to my device? There is no such logic implemented in the app. How do I correct this? Is it because the string being used is id? It works fine on pre-lollipop devices, but works wrongly on lollipop.

EDIT:

The way I am adding the values is as follows:

```
private void insertIntoDB() {
    int count = jsonArray.length();
    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[count];

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        JSONObject storeObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if(storeObject!=null){
            ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
            value.put(DBUtil.ID, storeObject.getInt("id"));
            mArrId.add(storeObject.getInt("id")+"");
            value.put("place_parent", storeObject.getInt("place_parent"));
        }
    }
    Cursor c1=new MylocalCursorLoader(mContext, "Delete from " + DBUtil.TABLE_MERCHANT_STORES).loadInBackground();
                if(c1!=null){
                    DBUtil dbUtil = DBUtil.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                    dbUtil.replaceOrUpdate(this, DBUtil.TABLE_MERCHANT_STORES, values,"merchant-stores");
                    mProgess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
}
```

MyLocalCursorLoader is a class extending CursorLoader. The storeObject.getInt("id") has values in the order of

514
533
531
312
434
162
253
252 
151
344
153
160
658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. If I remove UNIQUE while creating DBUtil.ID attribute in the table, then it works fine. I still don't know the exact reason for this. Would appreciate if someone can clarify the reason for this absurd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, it looks like the issue has something to do with the `ContentValues[]` being passed to your `replaceOrUpdate()` method.

You can add a log line to your loop in the method to verify if this is the case:

```
    for (int i=0; i<count;i++) {
        ContentValues value = contentValues[i];
        long id = mDatabase.replaceOrThrow(sTable,null,value);
        // Check output between Lollipop and earlier platform versions
        Log.v("DBUtil", "replaceOrThrow() returned " + id + "; value=" + value.toString());
    }
```

Otherwise, if you could post the code where the `ContentValues[]` gets populated, that might help you get a more direct answer more quickly.

Comment: I have printed the logs and checked it, the replaceOrThrow() outputs the ids in sequence from 1....786 and value.get(DBUtil.ID).toString() prints the  value that needs to be inserted i.e. 514, 533, 531, 312, 434, 162, 253, 252, 151,..., (set of integers in random order which are unique room numbers of each stores)

Comment: Are you including the column, `AUTO_ID`, in your `ContentValues`?  If so, if you log the associated value in the loop as in my answer, do they line up with what you see when you query the table afterward?  In other words, perhaps `replaceOrThrow()` is storing the value of `AUTO_ID` in the `ID` column?  I also noticed that you defined `DBUtil.ID` as lowercase `"id"`, but the column name is uppercase in your `CREATE TABLE`; `Cursor.getColumnIndex()` is case sensitive if I recall correctly, so that might also be causing some issues.

Comment: ID is a global variable with value "id". You can access it in other classes via DBUtil.ID. The column AUTO_ID, is autoincremented, so is not included in the ContentValues.

Comment: But you're using this variable to pass lower-case `id` as a column name to the case sensitive `Cursor.getColumnIndex()`, and the column name in your `CREATE TABLE` statement is a hard-coded uppercase `ID`.  This could cause some issues.  Regarding `AUTO_ID`, the `replaceOrThrow()` method requires a primary key in order to replace existing rows; if you're using `AUTOINCREMENT` on your primary key column, then `insertOrThrow()` is the more appropriate option.

Comment: The ID used to create table is again a global variable. It has already been changed in the question. If there were an issue in creating table columns then it would not be running on pre-lollipop devices

Comment: Gotcha. Then if, as you said, the `value.get(DBUtil.ID).toString()` outputs the values that were supposed to be inserted, then the use of `replaceOrThrow()` is probably the culprit.  Try  using `insertOrThrow()` instead, and make sure you're starting with a clean table.

Comment: I simply tried insert() and still the result doesnot change

Comment: If you uninstall the app first, that will make sure you start with a new database (learned that one the hard way).  Having used SQLite on Android for years, I'm very curious about what's going on here, but I think it's just going to take extensive logging and profiling to understand the issue.  BTW, if your device is rooted, you can copy the database to your pc via `adb pull /data/data/com.example.yourpackagename/databases/` and use whatever local SQLite tools you wish.  The SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox is pretty handy.  Hope this helps, and please do post if you find what went wrong.